# Management Studio without default colours

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Have this problem for a while, cannot see the usual colours on code editor (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio).
I am working on Windows 10 and here are the details:
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      13.0.15000.23
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                        13.0.1601.5
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     10.0.16299.15
Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     9.11.16299.0
Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                        6.3.16299

In this screenshot you can see that comments do not come in green for example:
[no comments in green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWiEJ.png)

SSMS language and operating system language is the same (English).

Also tried to change manually each one and does not work.

Many thanks!

Gonkas

Comment: You need to open file with `.sql` extension not arbitrary txt file

Comment: it is a file with a .sql extension